# Change vagrant php starting version

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, vagrant, homestead

I'm developing laravel app on [homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead) latest version.

I needed to add ImageMagick, as you know newest homestead is running on php7.0 but imagemagick is compatible so far with php5. So when I was installing it like this

```
vagrant ssh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
sudo apt-get install php5-imagick
```

I also needed to call `sudo apt-get install phpapi-20121212` because it's dependancy for php5-imagick

now... everytime when I provision vagrant I have to go to

```
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myproject.app
```

and change **fastcgi_pass unix:** from `/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock` **to** `/var/run/php5-fpm.sock`

is there some way or file where I can change this just once and then I don't have to do this process all over again after every provision?

Comment: You can install imagemagick from the PHP7 branch: see https://gist.github.com/sjelfull/69136fe74339025aa151 and https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/how-to-install-the-imagick-extension-for-php7

Answer (score 1):

Well i am not sure as i didn't used php5 for homestead or changed but this could help you.

If you look folder Homestead that you cloned from git this url :

```
git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead
```

In this directory you can find directory called `scripts`.

In script you can find file with name : `serve-hhvm.sh` you can edit this file in any editor like vim or sublime and change php path here then :

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

There is also a file called serve-laravel and this file have all settings related to laravel and path for php7 fpm file sock :

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
```

I hope this should fix your issue.